# How to decrease "Show Automatic Completions After Characters Entered" from 3 to 1 without getting "Internal Problem" error in Spyder IDE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, ide, spyder

I wanted to have a better autocompletion in Spyder IDE.
So I looked for the configurations about autocompletion and I found the "Completion and Linting" part in the Spyder preferences.
Then I found the "Show Automatic Completions After Characters Entered" option that was in this address :
Preferences >>> Completion and Linting >>> General(tab) >>> Completions(Section).

I have a big problem here :
When I Change the 3 to 1 and come back to my editor and type just a character, I see this page :
[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXY3z.png)

And when I close it and again start typing, I see this error page again.
I tried some ways to solve this problem.
I just could solve it by Resetting to default Setting.

When I did it, I didn't see it again.

But Again the "Show Automatic Completions After Characters Entered" is set to default value, I mean 3.

What should I do to solve the error without losing my changes in "Show Automatic Completions After Characters Entered"???

Please HELP me Solve This Problem

Comment: you should get full error message (Traceback) and read it - and later you should try to find it in code, debug it and fix it. And later you should write to Spyder's authors and describe it . Or you could use button `Submit to Github` to send this error ot Spyder's authors and maybe they will fix it. And you could also check if you get error also for `2`. Frankly, using `1` can makes problems because it has too many works to search all again and again after single char - and for single char you may get too many matching element and this can makes problem.

Comment: Hello, Thanks. I've got this error for the value 2(When I set it to 2 and type 2 characters).

Comment: You should send this to Spyder's authors as as bug in code. You could also check if it has problem with 4 or 5 chars - and send this information to Spyder's authors too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll do that